# Set-Cookie add 2 cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I have this class:

```js
var qs = require('querystring');

class Cookie
{
    constructor(req, res)
    {
        this.req = req;
        this.res = res;
    }

    get(name)
    {
        if (this.has(name))
        {
            var cookies = qs.parse(this.req.headers.cookie, '; ', '=');

            return cookies[name];
        }

        return null;
    }
    set(name, value)
    {
        this.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `${name}=${value};`)
    }

    delete(name)
    {
        if (this.has(name)) 
        {
            this.set(name, '')
        }
    }

    has(name)
    {
        if (typeof this.req.headers.cookie !== 'undefined') 
        {
            const cookies = qs.parse(this.req.headers.cookie, '; ', '=')

            return typeof cookies[name] !== 'undefined';
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And then i try this:

```js
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const cookie = new Cookie(req, res);
  
  cookie.set('name', 'Nikita')
  cookie.set('age', '13')
  
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.write('Now you have cookies')
  res.end()
  
}).listen(8000)
```

Then i looked in "Edit This Cookie" and see only last cookie (age=13)

I think this is because there is a variable in the response, where cookies are stored and when I use Set-Cookie, it sets the value for this variable, but how can I get the variables that I added before?

Comment: please review the answer @Nikita Shamberger, leave a comment if it doesn't work or accept it otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be only one `Set-Cookie` header, and you are overriding its value each time you call `cookie.set`.

The correct approach is to keep a local string variable in the class, and append the new `name=value` pair to it each time you call `cookie.set`

```
class Cookie
{
    var cookieString = ""

    // ...

    set(name, value)
    {  
        if (cookieString) 
        { 
            cookieString += '; '
        }

        cookieString += `${name}=${value}`
        this.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookieString)
    }

    //...
}
```